# there is empty ips in netstat

Tags: ddos, netstat, deflate

I have installed ddos deflate on my sever (centos6.5 64bit) and in server mailbox I see that ddos deflate has been blacklisted empty Ip.
and when I run this command on ssh I see:

```
netstat -ntu | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
...
3 2.186.85.154
3 5.134.135.148
3 5.239.236.176
3 5.250.23.249
3 78.39.67.226
3 95.80.153.13
4 87.248.150.152
9 199.201.121.153
22 95.80.176.162
762 127.0.0.1
4649
```

You see that there is 4649 connections from empty IP. what is cause of this problem and How can  I solve it?

Comment: Did you ever figure out this issue. I'm getting this right now.

Answer (score 5):

Your picking up ipv6 network connections which often have a number of colons in them. The `cut` command doesnt take this into account when snipping the colons out from the IP address.

Might be more suitable to use `egrep` instead of cut in that case I guess.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the problem lies with 'awk' and/or 'cut' commands. What I would do is run the following command:

```
netstat -ntu | awk '{print $5}' | egrep -v '127.0.0.1|95.80.176.162|199.201.121.153'
```

and look through it's output. Since the command shows 4649 whitespaces, I presume you'll figure it out when you see the output what's wrong. You will probably have to write a little more intelligent parsers for netstat and incorporate it into "ddos deflate". If you have trouble, post the output here.

Answer (score 1):

Its the problem with awk & cut command. You have to analyse the output of netstat first.

Follow [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261073/netstat-shows-over-44k-connections-without-ip-address-whats-that/261161#261161) question.